# What size was the most widely distributed version of Mao Zedong's "Little Red Book"?

Tags: china, mao-zedong

*Quotations From Chairman Mao*, known in the West as "the Little Red Book", was printed in China in several different sizes, of which [the most popular was a small size](https://www.colourstudies.com/blog/2017/5/8/little-red-book) that according to many accounts allowed it to be carried about with ease and to fit into a shirt pocket. What actually was this size?

Comment: My copy was about 4" by 6", that is, about 10 cm by 15 cm. The video clip at https://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-34932800 shows a modern British politician holding a copy of this size.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm not sure that was the most "popular" size though. That's on the small side for a book, but not really "little". A friend had a copy she got in China which was smaller. David Aaronovitch [says 6" too](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/articles/2gvyWgM76MSBS3dPwKyBL14/david-aaronovitch-on-how-maos-little-red-book-went-west), but another place [shows](https://www.pinterest.co.uk/pin/332984966169346232/) a 5" x 3.5" book, albeit for an English edition but still issued by the Chinese state so probably the same size as a Chinese edition.

Comment: The "most popular" edition is supposed to have fitted well into shirt pockets, and Sun Yat-sen suits or "Mao suits" as they are known in the West have big pockets so 6" x 4" is possible even if I'd call 5" x 3.5" more of a "pocket size" than 6" x 4" which is more of a "postcard size" that is used for quite a few paperback books. (That said, the "most popular" LRB edition had vinyl-covered cardboard boards and so wasn't a paperback, and one expects hardbacks to be bigger than paperbacks, so 6" x 4" might be "little" for a hardback.) The answer is probably one of these two sizes.

Comment: According to the [Bibliographical Society of America](https://bibsocamer.org/BibSite/Han/index.html), the first edition had "a page size larger than subsequent printings", having a height of 5+3/8 inches. There is a [copy](https://www.abebooks.com/servlet/BookDetailsPL?bi=30105266657) for sale at AbeBooks that is 126mm x 91mm or 5.0" x 3.6", which has roughly the height/width ratio I remember from my friend's copy, being smaller than 1.5. But this is all guesswork. Hopefully someone will answer who knows for a fact.

Comment: As @ruffle said, most popular size would be one that could fit in your shirt's breast pocket . Something like this : https://th.bing.com/th/id/R454e7c98e92f8c10e9491c2be841d6b5?rik=HMMoQJxolMiGyA&riu=http%3a%2f%2fchineseculturalrevolutionela12.weebly.com%2fuploads%2f7%2f9%2f6%2f0%2f79601634%2f7094190_orig.jpg&ehk=XRGckjyH6ApIqdIe2c8LcPbgrKlMuAfhqGK%2bB8e0xxo%3d&risl=&pid=ImgRaw